# Open source wiki on rails/ couchDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, wiki

Is there any good implementation of open source wiki using Rails and couchdb?
If not then which is the best option on rails platform, of course open source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at github's [gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum). it's a git based wiki system. absolutely awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know of is [Instiki](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/HomePage) (please note that the **maintained** home **is NOT** instiki.org, use the page I linked to). However it uses SQLite or MySQL.